# Sorting a list of dict from redis in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, redis

in my current project i generate a list of data, each entry is from a key in redis in a special DB where only one type of key exist.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_AD, port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db='14')

        item_list = []
        keys = r.keys('*')
        for key in keys:
            item = r.hgetall(key)
            item_list.append(item)
        newlist = sorted(item_list, key=operator.itemgetter('Id'))
```

The code above let me retrieve the data, create a list of dict each containing the information of an entry, problem is i would like to be able to sort them by ID, so they come out in order when displayed on my html tab in the template, but the sorted function doesn't seem to work since the table isn't sorted.

Any idea why the sorted line doesn't work ? i suppose i'm missing something to make it work but i can't find what.

EDIT :

Thanks to the answer in the comments,the problem was that my 'Id' come out of redis as a string and needed to be casted as int to be sorted

key=lambda d: int(d['Id'])

Comment: Are you sure the type of the value behind `'Id'` is the type you think it is? It might be a string, but you expect it to sort numerically.

Comment: Didn't think about that but yeah, every data from redis is a string, is there still a way to sort them ?

Comment: Write the key function yourself: `key=lambda d: int(d['Id'])`.

Comment: the perfect solution thanks a lot @Graipher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All values returned from redis are apparently strings and strings do not sort numerically (`"10" < "2" == True`).

Therefore you need to cast it to a numerical value, probably to `int` (since they seem to be IDs):

```
newlist = sorted(item_list, key=lambda d: int(d['Id']))
```